# ¿Cómo pasar variable php(laravel) desde el evento onclick a la función javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

al pasar la variable php(laravel) a la funcion javascript desde mi onclick me marca undefined
al pasarla sola me funciona y me dice 15 o 16 o un numero
y eso que la paso de la misma forma con printf

```
printf('<td class="td"><button id="' . $e->id_productos .'" class="button" onclick="(e)=> 
addToCarritoItem(e,'.$e->id_productos.')">Añadir</button></td>');

function addToCarritoItem(e,id){
  
  const id_parametro=id
  console.log('#'+id_parametro)
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ese que estoy mostrando añadi una foto, me sale undefined

Comment: ya lo edite, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: La forma correcta de pasar una función en el atributo `onclick`, en tu caso sería `onclick="addToCarritoItem(event,'.$e->id_productos.')"`

Comment: nop, me sigue saliendo undefined

Comment: ahora si, muchas gracias

Comment: En la pregunta que te respondí hace poco corregí la solución que te propuse y no funcionaba. Revisa la versión editada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo estas pasando bien pero no necesitas dos parámetros para el método

```
printf('<td class="td"><button id="' . $e->id_productos .'" class="button" 
onclick="(e)=> 
addToCarritoItem($e->id_productos)">Añadir</button></td>');

function addToCarritoItem(event){
  console.log(`#${event}`)
}
```